# What causes Vue props to equal [object Object] in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom

While inspecting the DOM for a Vue app in the Chrome console, I noticed there was an element with the attribute `content=[object Object]`. In the code, it's because that component was passing an object as a `content` prop to its child, and for some reason this was showing up in the DOM.

The component in question:
`<custom-component :content="obj" />`

I inspected other areas of the code that are also passing object props down to their children, and noticed that those props were absent from the DOM. Unfortunately, I could not find any significant differences that could be responsible for the discrepancy. Since I am trying to also hide `content=[object Object]` from the DOM, I was wondering what in Vue determines this behavior?

I tried to reproduce the behavior in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7gocyef/2/). However due to my question I can't figure out how to properly do that, and the `content` prop is absent from the DOM there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely because you haven't defined it as a prop on the relevant component. If it isn't defined as a prop then it'll just be converted to a string and added as an attribute to the outermost element of the component.

If your component does define this prop then check its template to see whether it is adding this attribute to its outermost element itself. If it's calling out to some other component at the root of the template then you'll similarly need to check whether that component defines this prop.

Answer (score 1):

The dom will register the prop as `[object Object]` if the component hasn't been registered properly, ie

```
import ExampleComponent from '...'
export default {
    components: { ExampleComponent },
}
```